# How to plot a hyperbolic vector field in R?

Tags: r, vector, graph, plot, hyperbolic-function

I am trying to plot a vector field like this:

http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full/2006/11/aa4228-05/img58.gif

which would have an equation of the form (y2 /b)-(x2 /k)=1,

in a plot something like this (http://math.haifa.ac.il/ROVENSKI/rovenski/images/ROV05_628.gif)

with nice little arrows and such.

Does anyone have any idea how this might be done?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that formula gives a hyperbolic field? Look pretty linear to me, .... and the vector field I can create with it doesn't match the example you offer. Maybe you should cite your sources and check your math.

Comment: A further comment after trimming the second URL: This was an academic site for a Israeli university course. If this is homework, does soliciting help on public forums conform to the the academic code of conduct for you institution?

Comment: This is not for homework, it is for work work, but that is one of the few places I saw it discussed online

Comment: Well, setting const*x+const*y=const is certianly not a hyperbola.

Comment: ... pretty sure that is how to express it in a cartesian plane

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola

Comment: You should learn to how represent superscripts or how the exponentiation operator is entered in R.

Answer (score 4):

```
df <- expand.grid(x=seq(-2, 2, .1), y=seq(-2, 2, .1)); k=2; b=4
df$z <- with(df, (y^2)-(x^2) )
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df)
projection(r) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
vectorplot(r, par.settings=RdBuTheme)
```

[image]

Ypu can play around with the arrow sizes. This setting seemed a bit more pleasing on my screen: `lwd.arrows=0.3,length=unit(.04, 'npc'))`